# Prove that the median of $y$ is $Q_{0.5}(y)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $x\sim f_{x}$ where $f_{x}$ is a continuous PDF. And $x$ is symmetric around $m$ so for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f_{x}(m-a)=f_{x}(m+a)$. Let $y=x-m$.

Given this, $y$ is also symmetric around $0$. I want to prove that median of $y$ is $Q_{0,5}(y)=0$.

This is the definition of the quantile I'm using: Let $x \sim  F_{x}$, and pick any $\alpha \in (0,1)$. The $\alpha$ quantile of $x$ is defined as: $$Q_{\alpha} (x) = q_{x}(\alpha) = \text{ inf}\left \{ b: \text{ Pr} (x \leq b) \geq \alpha \right \}.$$

So using the definition I have to show that $$Q_{0.5} (y) = q_{y}(0.5) = \text{ inf}\left \{ 0: \text{ Pr} (y \leq 0) \geq 0.5 \right \}.$$

In words, what does the definition mean?

I was wondering how I can use this fact $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(v)  dv=1$ to prove that $Q_{0.5}(y)=0$.

Comment: You have an error: $$q_{y}(0.5) = \inf\{b: \Pr\left(y \leq b\right) \geq 0.5\}\text{.}$$

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Notice that $Q_{\alpha}(x)$ changes ONLY $\alpha$ and $x$ inside the $\inf\{ \}$ part.

Comment: Okay so how do I do the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: It suffices to show that for an arbitrary continuous random variable $x$, if $f_x$ is symmetric around $m$, then $m$ is the median of $x$. I leave some of the details to you as questions.

By symmetry of $f_{x}$ around $m$ (using $t = v-m$, $u = -t$) , $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{m}f_{x}(v)\text{ d}v = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{m-m}f_{x}(t+m)\text{ d}t = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}f_{x}(t+m)\text{ d}t = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f_{x}(m-u)\text{ d}u =\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f_{x}(m+u)\text{ d}u\text{.}$$
But $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}f_{x}(t+m)\text{ d}t + \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f_{x}(m+u)\text{ d}u = 1$$
(why?) and thus $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{m}f_{x}(v)\text{ d}v = 0.5$$
(why?).

Since $f_y$ is symmetric around $0$ (as you have stated), then $0$ is the median of $y$.